# Volley - no response from the URL

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am unable to get any response from the URL I am hitting using the Volley library, please can you help me out ?

I am getting this on my emulator 
: "com.android.volley.NoConnectionError:java.io.IOexception:content length promised 45 bytes, but received 0 ."

I have pasted the code below:

String url = "http://ipchicken.com"

```
    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    sampletext.setText("Response => " + response.toString());


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    sampletext.setText( error.toString());

                }
            });

    queue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

Comment: if you can post your actual url, it would be easy to help you. For the error you described below, its either a problem with you internet connection or you should try changing the verbs(GET, POST) of request.

Comment: please change urlAddress and try again
String URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" __ send POST Method or GET ___test with this REST API

Answer (score 3):

If you constructed your `RequestQueue` by hand, instead of calling `Volley.newRequestQueue`, you need to call `.start()` on it. Otherwise it looks fine.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has been answered above: The url does not return any JSONObject, hence why you do not see any response [Your request is that of a JSONObject, meaning Volley expects JSONObject back as a response]. Maybe use the StringRequest instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why you use POST method? If you need exactly POST, where are params?

I think, you should use GET method and parse request to find your name address or something else.

Answer (score -1):

You most likely need to include the INTERNET uses-permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Hi Zambotron, I  already have the INTERNET uses permission in the manifest. This is the response i get : "com.android.volley.NoConnectionError:java.io.IOexception:content length promised 45 bytes, but received 0 .